# only mozilla use ssl certificate

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssl, certificate, opera

I'm using a proxy that can intercept http and https connections. For the httsp connections I use a certificate that I created. With mozilla I simply add the CA on `preferences > Advanced > Certificates > view certificates > authorities > import > .crt` and all works. If I do the same steps with both chrome and opera I can add the CA but I get Your connection is not private

why?

I created the .crt with

`openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj "/CN=proxy2 CA"
openssl genrsa -out cert.key 2048`

and then, with mozilla I import the .crt file

Comment: "If I do the same steps with both chrome and opera I can add the CA but I get Your connection is not private" - The certificate path should indicate the problem with the certificate.  You should verify you are adding the certificate to the operating system's certificate store for the entire machine not just the user's certificate store.  If you want help trying to debug the certificate provide the required information to do so.

Comment: I presume ‘‘httso’’ is a typo for ‘‘https’’.  Please [edit] your question to fix it.

Comment: @Ramhound I use linux and I added the .crt file to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and then `update-ca-certificates` but other browsers still not working

Comment: For Chrome on Linux, you add a certificate in a similar way as you did for Firefox.  Alternatively, you can use the NSS `certutil` tool directly on the database at `~/.pki/nssdb/`.

Comment: Chrome and Opera both will indicate the problem with an invalid certificate.  Provide that information by adding it to your question.  Any event my first comment was OS neutral by the way.

Comment: @garethTheRed with the similar way chrome and opera don't work, I als tried with the `certutil`, but still nothing

Answer (score 1):

There might be a couple of issues with your setup:

You generated a self signed certificate, you should generate a CA keypair, self-sign that, install it in the client's ca_trust, and enable trust. The CA should sign a certificate request that includes a subjectAltName extension and a FQDN. You have a local DNS right?

Comment: hi, sorry but I don't know much of these things. I generated that .crt and then the proxy that I'm using downloaded the same file by the browser. Then I added the .crt in mozilla authorities.